# is there any tool to handle sqlite operations in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i am new to sqlite in iphone.

i am creating table and inserting values into that table.

But what happen is i did n't get weather table is create or not,weather values are insert or not.

For the nsurl web requests we have a tool named `charles`.With this we can able to find which operations is going on is request is sent or not what response we got.

So that we can able to find mistakes very easily.

is there any tool for sqlite,to check weather table is create or not values insert or by programmatically in our application is some what difficult.

So experts can any one please suggest is there any tool to handle sqlite operations in iphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such tool for tracking operation (insertion,Deletion etc.) at run time, but once you done with any one of your DB operation,you can check the table content by using a **adds On** called **SQLite Manager** , it install on Mozilla web browser,

---

**SQLite Manager**  has the following feature...

Manage any SQLite database on your computer.

An intuitive heirarchical tree showing database objects.

Helpful dialogs to manage tables, indexes, views and triggers.

You can browse and search the tables, as well as add, edit, delete and duplicate the 
records.

Facility to execute any sql query.

The views can be searched too.

A dropdown menu helps with the sql syntax thus making writing sql easier.

Easy access to common operations through menu, toolbars, buttons and context-menu.

Export tables/views/database in csv/xml/sql format. Import from csv/xml/sql (both UTF-8 and UTF-16).

Possible to execute multiple sql statements in Execute tab.

You can save the queries.

Support for ADS on Windows.

and here is the link to install

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

It's great tool that make very easy to work on sqllite database.

Comment: You are right. SQlite Manager is a good and easy to use tool :)